# Check if a column is indexed - MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, indexing

I need to write a script to check if a column is indexed in the table it belongs to, if not then add an index for it.  MySQL doesn't seem to have `ADD INDEX IF NOT EXISTS`.

What's the best way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

There is a stored procedure that does this (remember, not my code, just
the first hit on google with `mysql add index if not exists` as search string).

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_index_if_not_exists`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_index_if_not_exists`(table_name_vc varchar(50), index_name_vc varchar(50), field_list_vc varchar(200))
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

set @Index_cnt = (
select  count(1) cnt
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE   table_name = table_name_vc
and index_name = index_name_vc
);

IF ifnull(@Index_cnt,0) = 0 THEN set @index_sql = concat('Alter table ',table_name_vc,' ADD INDEX ',index_name_vc,'(',field_list_vc,');');

PREPARE stmt FROM @index_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

There is an alternative version right underneath it in the same page.

Comment: Fantastic, i think this is exactly what i need. I'm sure i've looked at that page but missed this somehow. Stupid me, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you along:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM my_table WHERE Key_name = 'index_to_check';
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, however i'm not sure how to put it in an IF condition to add the index if it not exists?  Would be great if i can have something like: IF (the query above returns a result) THEN ADD INDEX abc...